# Add TypeScript typings to a top-level (npm-like) module

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add typings to a top-level module, basically I want

```
import DropDownButton from 'bootstrap-dropdown-button'
```

to be typed correctly.  Inside of `typings/bootstrap-dropdown-button/index.d.ts` I have the following

```
import {Component} from 'react';

declare module 'bootstrap-dropdown-button' {
    //var DropdownButton: any;
    //export default DropdownButton;

    export default class DropdownButton extends Component<any, any> {}
}
```

which does not work.  I get errors of

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'bootstrap-dropdown-button'.

But, if I remove the existing code and uncomment

```
var DropdownButton: any;
export default DropdownButton;
```

then everything works fine, though naturally my typings for this module are fairly weak.

It seems my typing does not work when I try to load up the `Component` type from react.  The react typings have been loaded via npm through `@types/react` and work fine, otherwise.

How should I adjust my typing code so `bootstrap-dropdown-button` is recognized by TypeScript, and interacts correctly with `React.Component`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to coexist peacefully both with ES module-style importing/exporting as well as ambient modules, TypeScript type definition files can be a little bit strange to follow, especially when cross-referencing them. Let's take a look at the type definitions in `@types/react` to see what's going on:

```
export = React;
export as namespace React;

declare namespace React {

    // a great many things, including:

    interface Component<P, S> extends ComponentLifecycle<P, S> { }
    class Component<P, S> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

What's basically going on here is that a TypeScript [namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) is being defined with React's types, and the `export` statements atop it indicate that the namespace's members should be used when referencing the `react` package as an ES module.

The advantage to this method of declaring types is that both ambient and ES module situations are supported. The disadvantage is that it can be a little bit unclear about how to reference those types in some cases.

The key to remember here is that although React itself is exposed through an ES module (since you're `import`ing it), its *types* can be referenced both via the module and via the namespace. But since you're trying to create a downstream type definition, you need to use the *namespace* because TypeScript doesn't treat type definition files like ES modules (though they specify types to be used with them).

```
declare module 'bootstrap-dropdown-button' {
    export default class DropdownButton extends React.Component<any, any> {}
    //                                          ^^^^^^
}
```

In your type definition file, just qualify the external types you use with their namespace instead of trying to import them as a module.